# MATLAB: Limiting range of plotted values

Tags: matlab

I'm not a Matlab user at all but I'm merely trying to use now it create a quick and dirty 2D plot to illustrate relative O-notation complexities to avoid drawing it by hand.  I am using Matlab version R2010b and I have no additional toolkits.  My question consists of two parts.  I would like plots of the following cases on the same plot:

```
O(1)
O(lg2 n)
O(n)
O(n lg2 n)
O(n * n)
O(2 ^ n)
O(n!)
```

My code is at the end of this post.

Question 1: Although I have specified the range of values for n and my axis limits as I want them, obviously the value of n-squared and n-factorial will greatly exceed the desired y-axis range.  When this happens it greatly compresses the y axis plot in order to accommodate that range of outputs.  How can I specify that no values of y should be plotted past the desired range of the desired range of the y axis itself?

Question 2: In my code below the expression n * log2(n) results in an error stating "Inner matrix dimensions must agree."  I got the same error when I tried to compute n-squared by simply doing n * n, but I was able to resolve that by changing it to n.^2.  What is the proper way to express n * log2(n) ?

Thanks,
Ray

```
grid on
axis([0,40,0,200]);
n = 0:1:40;

O_1 = 0;
O_log2_n = log2(n);
O_n = n;
O_n_log2_n = n * log2(n);    % Doesn't work this way
O_log2_nSq = n.^2;
O_log2_nFact = factorial(n);

plot(n, O_1, n, O_log2_n, n, O_n, n, O_n_log2_n, n, O_log2_nSq, n, O_log2_nFact);

text(37, 37, '   O(n)', 'HorizontalAlignment','left','FontSize',12);
set(gca, 'XTick', [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]);
set(gca, 'YTick', [0, 50, 100, 150, 200]);
xlabel('n','FontSize',16);
ylabel('T(n)','FontSize',16);
title('\it{Comparative algorithm growth rates}','FontSize',16);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out [ylim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html)
2. Do element-by-element multiplication with `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator in Matlab is a matrix multiplier. Thus, it only works if the second dimension of the first matrix is the same as the first dimension of the second matrix (and it doesn't work at all if the matrices are not two dimensional).

The `.*` operator works on a "per element" basis: so in the expression `C=A.*B`, you get

```
C(1,1) = A(1,1) * B(1,1);
C(1,2) = A(1,2) * B(1,2);
```

etc.

Note - for `.*`, the matrices must have the same dimensions: A(N, M) and B(N, M). For the `*` operation, you must have A(M, N) and B(N, P). Also note - any "vector" in Matlab is actually a 1xN (row) or Nx1 (column) matrix...

To answer your question "what is the proper way to express `n*log2(n)`" - use `n.*log2(n);`

As for plotting things on different scales: you can use `semilogy` which plots with a logarithmic Y scale (no use if you have zeros in the Y values) or use `ylim([lower upper])` as a separate statement after the `plot` command to get the output in range.

If you want to be clever and use semilogy while you have zeros in the Y values, you can do something like this:

```
notZero = find(Y>0);
semilogy(X(notZero),Y(notZero);
```